when select data that I imported from csv file, it return bar sign (|)
code I used:
LOAD DATA INFILE 'F:\\r-analysis\\202004-divvy-tripdata.csv'
INTO TABLE 2020_04_divvy_tripdata
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;

and I got the output of:
Query OK, 199953 rows affected (2.85 sec)
Records: 199953  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

but when I run following code, the data is unusual:
select member_casual from 2020_04_divvy_tripdata limit 2;

result:
+---------------+
| member_casual |
+---------------+
       |
       |
+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

at the same time when I run following code, it shows:
select ride_id, rideable_type, member_casual from 2020_04_divvy_tripdata limit 1;

something like this:
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
| ride_id          | rideable_type | member_casual |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
       |D35674B983 | docked_bike   | member
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

example of my csv file:
ride_id,rideable_type,started_at,ended_at,start_station_name,start_station_id,end_station_name,end_station_id,start_lat,start_lng,end_lat,end_lng,member_casual
02668AD35674B983,docked_bike,2020-05-27 10:52,2020-05-27 10:49,Franklin St & Jackson Blvd,36,Wabash Ave & Grand Ave,199,41.8777,-87.6353,41.8915,-87.6268,member
7A50CCAF1EDDB28F,docked_bike,2020-05-25 10:11,2020-05-25 11:40,Clark St & Wrightwood Ave,340,Clark St & Leland Ave,326,41.9295,-87.6431,41.9671,-87.6674,casual
2FFCDFDB91FE9A52,docked_bike,2020-05-02 14:03,2020-05-02 15:21,Kedzie Ave & Milwaukee Ave,260,Kedzie Ave & Milwaukee Ave,260,41.9296,-87.7079,41.9296,-87.7079,casual


What should I do?

Provide complete output for SHOW CREATE TABLE 2020_04_divvy_tripdata;. Check if LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' is correct - maybe your file is Windows-type and uses '\r\n' as line terminator?

It should work check your csv file data. There might be some blank row or terminator format may different and that's why it's throwing error.
If you are still getting issue, then drop existing table & re-create again....
My end SQL sample query:
drop table if exists TT;
CREATE TABLE TT (
    col1 int,
    col2 varchar(255),
    col3 varchar(255)
);
-- SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\tt.csv'
INTO TABLE TT
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;

Select * from TT;

Response:

Must create .csv file valid way(don't change extension of the file):

During .csv import if you get error like
The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Then use following steps:

Run query in MySQL: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
Check MySQL output and copy directory path
Mover your files to that directory
Closed & Reopen MySQL application for synchronization of that file.
Re-run your script

It should work.
Thank You

Oh, thanks for your answer, but I found out that when I use GUI (MySQL Workbench) data shows correctly, but the problem is when I use raw SQL queries on CLI that data it's showing is not accurate. I can't understand why...
